# LIKE 'string' and LIKE '%string%' in mysql not working as same

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-like

I have confusion in the above title.

```html
SELECT * FROM `parties` WHERE `party_name` LIKE '%DMK%' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Here I am getting 4 rows from DB, all row's party_name contains 'DMK' inside.

```
SELECT * FROM `parties` WHERE `party_name` LIKE 'DMK' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Here I am getting exact one row which contains party_name as 'DMK'

The first query is searching the part of strings.
the second query is searching the exact string

IS it ??

or both are same?

Sorry for this type of question ,
Thanx

Comment: the `%` is a wild card it's saying search for `*DMK*` - pretty much meaning **any** string that contains DMK. The other (without wildcards) matches the pattern DMK. So a string has to === DMK to return.

Comment: Maybe [pattern-matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) will be helpful for further information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `LIKE` without % wild card is the same behavoiur of equals (`=`).

So if you write:

```
 SELECT * FROM parties WHERE party_name LIKE 'DMK' ORDER BY id ASC
```

Is the same of:

```
SELECT * FROM parties WHERE party_name = 'DMK' ORDER BY id ASC
```

If you write:

```
SELECT * FROM `parties` WHERE `party_name` LIKE '%DMK%' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

You'll find all party_name who cointains DMK

If you write:

```
SELECT * FROM `parties` WHERE `party_name` LIKE '%DMK' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

You'll find all party_name ends with DMK

If you write:

```
SELECT * FROM `parties` WHERE `party_name` LIKE 'DMK%' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

You'll find all party_name starts with DMK

Comment: I was very much confused between those two now its cleared, thanx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `parties` WHERE `party_name` LIKE '%DMK%' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

mean all string that contain  DMK eg ('DMK1, 'ADMK', ADMKB')

```
SELECT * FROM `parties` WHERE `party_name` LIKE 'DMK' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

mean all string equal to   DMK  as  and is equivalent  to

```
SELECT * FROM `parties` WHERE `party_name` = 'DMK' ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
party_name LIKE 'DMK'
```

will match only column with value 'DMK' . it essentially the same as 
party_name ='DMK'

```
party_name LIKE '%DMK%'
```

this will match string where 'DMK' exist anywhere
example . abcDMK , abcDMKefg , DMKabc

```
party_name LIKE '%DMK'
```

this will match string where 'DMK' exist at the last 
example : it will match abcDMK  but it will not match abcDMKefg

```
party_name LIKE 'DMK%'
```

this will match string where 'DMK' exist in the beginning
example : it will not abcDMK  but it will not match abcDMKefg